# External JS on Joomla and WordPress not loading

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, joomla

I need some help with a script `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.carloansjoplin.com/web/trbo/trbo.js">`
 I placed in a Joomla template at http://twsshosting.com/~dynaredo/ - this should load a promotional layer after 2 page views. It works fine on the test page http://www.carloansjoplin.com/web/trbo/test.html - I also eliminated the possibility that the problem could be the cross domain ajax connection through adjustment of the .htaccess. I tested it on different servers with custom html pages and it works just fine. The same problem comes up with worldpress sites (so it must be a problem with the template engines).

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of where you're importing it. If you see on the *test.html* page, it's being imported in the `<head>`.

So what you should do is (for Joomla), is import it using PHP like so:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript("http://www.carloansjoplin.com/web/trbo/trbo.js");
```

This should be inserted inside PHP tags towards the top of your template.

Comment: Thanks! I imported it with the php tags and it is still not working. Any more suggestions?

Comment: ah I see now that the *trbo.js* file is calling an external PHP file. Joomla doesn't like this as it expects everything to stick to it's own coding standards. You might want to look into developing a small simple module

Comment: There is an error in the console on the Joomla site which could possibly well be a Mootools conflict

Comment: I noticed the error. I removed the part with the conflict and the script is still not pulling in.